# Unable to play torrent download video file

Tags: video, bittorrent, vlc-media-player

I downloaded a movie and when I play it in VLC or Windows Media player - I get text over the movie being played - "Codec Error:Use Windows Media Player" followed by "Aborting video, redirected to Microsoft Codec Download page". The hour long video runs only for 15 seconds and opens a page on some torrent page which asks me to fill a survey form(which is irresponsive) to download VLC player again.

Is there any way I can work around it?

Comment: Comments removed since they were purely speculative and not based on facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> opens a page on some torrent page
>   which asks me to fill a survey
>   form(which is irresponsive) to
>   download

Dubious. Survey filling for a codec is a sure-shot giveaway for spam and email harvesting or other sorts of (drive-by) malware. Stay away from it.

Comment: @fixxxer: Agreed - looks like a virus. DO NOT play in Windows Media Player! DO NOT download or install anything from this "survey" !!

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I found the solution  to my problem - 
http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=64879

> These videos are 'hacked' videos that contain scripts which can be executed by WMP only. The purpose of this is to force you to be redirected to another site and/or to download some stuff in the background.
>   If you can't play them in WMP then it's a good sign meaning that your Windows and WMP are correctly patched with the latest security updates.
>
> Anyway you should delete these videos as soon as possible because they may compromise the security of your computer if they are played in WMP.